# eclipse project only run once

Tags: c++, eclipse

please,I am a new eclipse c++ user,and I am facing a strange problem,any project I create will run once,but after any small change eclipse show error message and the project refuse to run till I delete the project .exe file from the project folder

Comment: Well, I'll ask the obvious, **what does the error message say?**

Comment: If the error message is something like "cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied", odds are the program is still running. If, on the other hand, it says "Know nyarlathotep, know fear." I recommend turning the computer off and enjoying the last few pleasurable minutes of your life with friends and family.

Comment: yub,its the "cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied" ,how can i close it?

Comment: Window->perspective->Open perspective->debug (or other. You might have to go fishing if you haven't been in the debug perspective before). Top left pane of the debug perspective should be the programs running and being debugged. Click on the root of anything that's still running and then click the red square terminate button on the tool bar just below the menu. If there is nothing in the debug pane, something else is going on.